# How to dock a skewed div to the above div?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I tried to add a div to another div, so that its upper border won't move if its skewed.

**Html Code:**

```
 <div class="Container">
      <div class="Main"> </div>
      <div class="Shadow"></div>
 </div>
```

**Css Code:**

```
.Shadow
{
    height:70px;
    width:30px;
    transform:skew(20deg);
    background-color:lightgray;
}
.Container {
    display:inline-block;
}
.Main
{
    width:30px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
}
}
```

[Demofiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6HFs/)

The following moves the shadow div's border.
Is there a way to avoid this and "dock" the shadow div's upper side to the Maindiv, so that it won't move (even when changing 'skew' in an animation)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by using the `transform-origin` property. Just set it like below and it will make sure that the top of the shadow div is always docked to the bottom of the main div.

```
.Shadow {
    height:70px;
    width:30px;
    -webkit-transform:skew(20deg);
    -moz-transform:skew(20deg);
    transform:skew(20deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top; /* add this setting */
    -moz-transform-origin: left top; /* add this setting */
    transform-origin: left top; /* add this setting */
    background-color:lightgray;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b6HFs/3/) | [**Transform Origin - MDN Spec**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Comment: Nice solution +1. Maybe remove the *-webkit-* prefix (or add the others) in your fiddle so other browsers will support it too.

Comment: @BudBrot: Yes, mate. My browser is too old (:D) so had to use the prefixed version. Will update it now :) *Edit:* Done :)